# Calculate the posterior probability in two groups, Pr(p1>p2 | Data)?

Tags: r, probability, posterior, beta-binomial-distribution

Assume the prior distribution of p1 and p2:

**p1~beta(1,1)**

**p2~beta(2,3)**

Assume the data in group1 and group2 follows bernouli distribution:

**y1~Binom(10,0.3)**

**y2~Binom(10,0.6)**

How can I calculate the probability Pr(p1>p2|Data) under observation **Data** in R?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that probabilities in the likelihoods are estimates (i.e. you got 3 successes in group 1 and 6 in the other, else you don't need to do inference).

Because the prior and likelihood are conjugate, the posterior densities in each group are

$$  P(p_1 \vert y_1) \sim \operatorname{Beta}(1+3, 1 + 7) $$

$$ P(p_2 \vert y_2) \sim \operatorname{Beta}(2+6, 1 + 4) $$

One way to estimate $P(p_1>p_2 \vert y_1, y_2)$ is to just draw from these distributions and count how many times the draw from the first distribution is greater than the draw from the second.  In R...

```
set.seed(0)
num_samples = 1e6
p_1_samp = rbeta(num_samples, 1+3, 1+7)
p_2_samp = rbeta(num_samples, 2+6, 1+4)
mean(p_1_samp > p_2_samp)
>>>0.069911
```

This depends on the random seed we use.  To find a more accurate answer, you could compute the difference between the random variables by performing a convolution.

Comment: Many thanks! But can I use `dbeta` to calculate the PDF instead? e.g. `library(pracma);
f<-function(x,y,pE1,y1,y2,n) dbeta(x,y1+0.3,n-y1+0.7)*dbeta(y,y2+0.3,n-y2+0.7);
xmin=0;
xmax=1;
ymin=0;
ymax=function(x) x;
integral2(f,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,y1=3,n=10,y2=6);`